# Black spots in the kitchen sink

Tags: mold

I just moved into a new flat and there seems to be some black spots in the kitchen sink(image attached).Is this black mold?How can I get rid of them safely?[image]

PS: There is some black mold lining on the wall in the outer edge of the sink.And I am allergic to bleach

Update : I tried scrubbing it today with dish soap and it washed away very easily. I am now more worried if that could be mold or just dirt/buildup :(

Comment: Mold would wash right off that surface. Have you tried?

Comment: Have you tried scrubbing power?

Comment: Please don't call it an allergy. It's sensitivity to bleach. http://acaai.org/allergies/types/allergy-myths/chlorine-allergy .

Comment: I tried scrubbing it with dish soap and it washed away very easily. I am now more worried if that could be mold or just dirt/buildup :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are allergic to bleach get some hydrogen peroxide. It will kill mold and mildew. I purchase my Hydrogen peroxide at a local chemical supply house and dilute to 3% with water. Remember when using concentrated hydrogen peroxide always add it to the water to dilute. Then spray or wipe down and let it sit for a few minutes and rinse. It may brighten the sink enamel if stained so be prepared to do the entire sink. I learned this sanitizing trick when working for a hospital, no bleach smell and it kills the nastys.